# how to access div with period in its class in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to access a div who have a period in its class i.e `clazz.id`, but the length returned is 0

I have a made the following jsFiddle to illustrate my issue

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kamranali377/WrdXB/)

here is my **html**

```
<div id="activity-operation" style="" class="edit-form">
    <form class="form1">
        <div class="server-error" style="display: none;"></div>
        <fieldset>
            <div>
                <input id="c49_id" name="id" type="hidden" class="myClassCustom" value="1">
            </div>
            <div>
                <input id="c49_subject_id" name="subject_id" type="hidden" class="myClassCustom" value="37">
            </div>
            <div>
                <input id="c49_activityValidationType" name="activityValidationType" type="hidden" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="input swField-name">
                <div class="inputtext">
                    <label for="c49_name" style="float:right;">Activity Name</label>
                </div>
                <div class="inputcontent">
                    <input id="c49_name" name="name" readonly="readonly" disabled="disabled" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="input-error" style="display:none;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="input swField-subject.name">
                <div class="inputtext">
                    <label for="c49_subject_name" style="float:right;">Subject</label>
                </div>
                <div class="inputcontent">
                    <input id="c49_subject_name" name="subject_name" readonly="readonly" disabled="disabled" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="input-error" style="display:none;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="input swField-activityType.id">
                <div class="inputtext">
                    <label for="c49_activityType_id" style="float:right;">Select Type</label>
                </div>
                <div class="inputcontent">
                    <select id="c49_activityType_id" name="activityType_id">
                        <option value="ASIG">Assignment</option>
                        <option value="CLAS">Class</option>
                        <option value="QUIZ">Quiz</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="input-error" style="display:none;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="input swField-term.id">
                <div class="inputtext">
                    <label for="c49_term_id" style="float:right;">Select Term</label>
                </div>
                <div class="inputcontent">
                    <select id="c49_term_id" name="term_id">
                        <option value="FA12">Fall 2012</option>
                        <option value="FA13">Fall 2013</option>
                        <option value="SP12">Spring 2012</option>
                        <option value="SP13">Spring 2013</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="input-error" style="display:none;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="input swField-grading">
                <div class="inputtext">
                    <label for="c49_grading" style="float:right;">Grading</label>
                </div>
                <div class="inputcontent">
                    <input id="c49_grading" name="grading" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="input-error" style="display:none;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="input swField-class.id error">
                <div class="inputtext">
                    <label for="c49_clazz_id" style="float:right;">Select Class</label>
                </div>
                <div class="inputcontent">
                    <select id="c49_clazz_id" name="clazz_id">
                        <option value="">Select</option>
                        <option value="22">10</option>
                        <option value="10">9b</option>
                        <option value="11">9c</option>
                        <option value="40">A</option>
                        <option value="41">B</option>
                        <option value="24">c1</option>
                        <option value="25">c2</option>
                        <option value="26">c3</option>
                        <option value="27">c4</option>
                        <option value="87">Obj 1</option>
                        <option value="86">Rawalpindi Board</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="input-error" style="display:none;">Class is required</div>
            </div>
            <div class="input swField-section.id">
                <div class="inputtext">
                    <label for="c49_section_id" style="float:right;">Select Section</label>
                </div>
                <div class="inputcontent">
                    <select id="c49_section_id" name="section_id" readonly="readonly" disabled="disabled">
                        <option value="select"></option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="input-error" style="display:none;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="input swField-description">
                <div class="inputtext">
                    <label for="c49_description" style="float:right;">Description</label>
                </div>
                <div class="inputcontent">
                    <textarea id="c49_description" name="description" type="text"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="input-error" style="display:none;"></div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="buttons">
            <input class="orangebutton swFormSubmitButton" type="submit" value="Submit">
            <input class="greybutton swFormCancelButton" type="submit" value="Cancel">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

and these are the selectors i'm trying

```
alert($("form.form1").find(".swField-clazz\\\\.id div.inputcontent").length);

alert($("form.form1").find(".swField-clazz\\.id div.inputcontent").length);
```

I've tried `\\`  to escape the period in the class but it does not seem to be working

Comment: You should really try to get rid of periods in your classnames. It's invalid.

Comment: Have you tried using just a single backslash? `\.`

Comment: i'm just fixing some already written code, so can't really help modifying it :(

Comment: Jrod yes but the same result

Comment: I can't see any class named `swField-clazz.id` in your HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escaping with `\\` actually works.

There is simply no such class as `swField-clazz.id` in your HTML.

Try to get rid of your periods in your class names, though.

Answer (score 2):

This works fine:
`alert($("form.form1").find(".swField-activityType\\.id div.inputcontent").length);`

See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WrdXB/1/